# Lambda function, strange behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Let's assume we have the following lambda declared in the global namespace:

```
auto Less = [](int a,int b) -> bool
{
    return a < b;
}
```

And the following code which make use of this lambda:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo(int v){}
    bool operator<(const foo<T>&) const
    {
        return T(1,2);
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef foo<decltype(Less)> be_less;
    priority_queue<be_less> data;
}
```

As you can see I use `Less` as template parameter for the struct `foo`. With g++4.9.2 this code does not compile:

```
test1.cpp:13:21: error: no matching function for call to '<lambda(int, int)>::__lambda0(int, int)'
     return T(1,2);
                 ^
test1.cpp:13:21: note: candidates are:
test1.cpp:17:14: note: constexpr<lambda(int, int)>::<lambda>(const<lambda(int, int)>&)
 auto Less = [](int a,int b) -> bool
          ^
test1.cpp:17:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
test1.cpp:17:14: note: constexpr<lambda(int, int)>::<lambda>(<lambda(int, int)>&&)
test1.cpp:17:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Bu I may fix this problem adding two small changes, first of all I need to change the lambda into this:

```
bool Less = [](int a,int b) -> bool
{
    return a < b;
}
```

As you can see i just replaced `auto` with `bool`, this modification alone still does not work:

```
test1.cpp:13:21: error: expression list treated as compound expression in functional cast [-fpermiss
ive]
     return T(1,2);
```

Unless I add `-fpermissive`, or i may change the `operator<` `bool` in this way:

```
bool operator<(const foo<T>&) const
{
    return T((1,2));
}
```

Note the double parentheses. Now the code compile and everything work.

My question is, which is the technical reason why `auto Less` does not work but `bool Less` work?

I believe I know why the double parentheses are required in the second `operator<`, this should be to avoid the compiler to interpret `T(1,2)` as a declaration instead of a call.

Thanks for your time

Comment: `T(1,2)` is trying to make a new instance of the lambda by passing two numbers to its constructor. You probably wanted an instance of the lambda to call instead. In the case where you make `Less` a `bool`, it's like saying `bool(1,2)`, which makes no sense, and I'm not knowedgeable about the GCC extension that comes into play when you use `-fpermissive` (not an option I like to use).

Comment: So you probably want `return T()(1,2);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first example you're constructing `foo<T>` where `[T = decltype(Less)]`. So in this expression

```
return T(1,2);
```

you're trying to construct an instance of the lambda by invoking a constructor that takes 2 `int`s, which obviously doesn't exist. That's exactly what the error message is telling you

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to '<lambda(int, int)>::__lambda0(int, int)'
> ```

The only constructors that exist are the copy and move constructors for the lambda (the closure type created from a lambda expression is not default constructible), which the compiler tries to match the arguments against and fails

```
constexpr<lambda(int, int)>::<lambda>(const<lambda(int, int)>&)
constexpr<lambda(int, int)>::<lambda>(<lambda(int, int)>&&)
```

> ```
> candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
> ```

---

In the second case, by making this change

```
bool Less = [](int a,int b) -> bool
{
    return a < b;
};
```

what you've done is declare a boolean variable named `Less` and initialize it to `true`.

This is because the lambda expression you have is capture-less, which means it can be implicitly converted into a pointer to a function that takes the same arguments as the lambda's `operator()` and returns the same type as the original lambda. So you convert the lambda expression to `bool(*)(int,int)`.

Next, a function pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool` and will always evaluate to `true` (assuming it actually points to the address of a function, which it does here). So `Less` gets initialized to `true`.

Now, `decltype(Less)` is nothing but `bool`. So here you're trying a function style cast to `bool`, but passing in 2 arguments

```
return T(1,2);
```

Hence the error

> ```
> error: expression list treated as compound expression in functional cast
> ```

By adding the extra parentheses you have an expression consisting of 2 sub-expressions separated by the comma operator. This will evaluate and discard the first sub-expression (`1`) and return the value of the second (`2`) which is then cast to `bool`, so it converts to `true`.

---

I'm not really sure what you're attempting to do to be able to suggest a solution, but if all you want is define some comparison predicate for `foo` that'll then be invoked by the `priority_queue`, then maybe the following works?

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int v) {}
};

auto Less = [](foo const& a, foo const& b) -> bool
{
    return true; // do whatever comparison you need 
};

int main()
{
    using my_priority_queue = std::priority_queue<foo, std::vector<foo>, decltype(Less)>;

    my_priority_queue data(Less); // pass a copy of the comparator 
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3c17af67a63936b)

Answer (score 1):

First case:

In the statement

```
return T(1,2);
```

`T` is a type, the type of the lambda expression. `T(1, 2)` tries to construct an instance of that type, which I don't think is possible. That explains the compiler error message. I am not sure how you can just use the type and invoke the function.

In the second case, `T` is `bool`.

`bool(1, 2)` is not a valid expression. That explains the error message.
`bool((1, 2))` is `bool(2)`, which is a valid expression that evaluates to `true`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to get a lambda object to use and you need access to the variable initialized with the lambda expression.